# Using Python, Cython, and GSL on cluster

Tags: python, linux, cython, gsl

I am hoping to run my Python program on a cluster computing system.  Since I do not have root access on each node of the cluster, I need to install Python and my modules in a local directory and run my code from there.  In order to save time, I am able to do a local Python build on one of the nodes, tar it, and save the tarred Python on a proxy server.  Then, when I want to run my code on the rest of nodes I simply wget the tarred Python, untar it, and then run my program.  So basically I only need to build Python once, and then can use it repeatedly on the cluster; the code I run on the cluster looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget www.proxyserver.Local_Python_Build.tgz
tar xzf Local_Python_Build.tgz
./Local_Python_Build/bin/python my_python_code.py
```

I am running into a one major issues.  First, my main code uses some Cython programs I have written that requires GSL. When I do the initial install of Python, I also do a local build of GSL, as well as compile the Cython code (all of which is included in the tar).  I've checked to make sure that everything runs correctly after I build it, but the code does not work once I submit it on the cluster.  I keep getting the following error:

```
ImportError: libgsl.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Now, I've tried adding the path to the directory where libgsl.so.0 is located in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but that does not work; ie

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/where/libgsl/is
```

I am worried that I will need to build GSL each time I run the my code; ie run the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget www.proxyserver.Local_Python_Build.tgz
tar xzf Local_Python_Build.tgz
install GSL
Compile Cython Code
./Local_Python_Build/bin/python my_python_code.py
```

This will obviously add to my run time, which I'm hoping to avoid.  Anyone ideas?  The computing cluster runs Linux.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of cluster? See if virtualenv is installed. It may allow you to install required tools within.

Comment: Its a Linux cluster.  The nodes are pretty lean and I'm pretty sure virtualenv is not installed. But I can check.v Some additional information: there are a number of different distributions of Linux on the cluster, and the program runs fine on some (for example RHEL 6.6) but not on other (RHEL 6.4).

Comment: What error do you get on RHEL 6.4 ?

Comment: The error I get on RHEL 6.4 is:    ImportError: libgsl.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Also, with some of the other distributions I get the following error:   ImportError: libptf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.  So the path is ATLAS is messed up as well.

Comment: Have you tried just copying those files from your front node, and setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` accordingly?

Comment: I have not!  I will try that and see if that works. Although I thought that when you compile ATLAS its very much platform specific, so I'm not sure if you can simply move the .so file from one system to another.  But I'll try and it and see what happens

Answer (score 2):

Building GSL at every run (or Python for that matter) should definitely not be necessary. Assuming, all the nodes have access to some shared file system, you could simply,

1. Build Python, GSL and compile your Cython code in a shared folder
2. In the file that you submit to the batch queue system, you change the environment variable (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `PATH`, etc) so it can find the executables and the necessary libraries.

The reason why that could have failed is that `path/where/libgsl/is` is not mounted on the nodes. Check with the system administrator regarding that issue. The specifics of the batch system used will also influence how to make this work.

Comment: So I do not believe that the nodes do have access to a shared file system.  I was told that the only way I could run my program was to build Python and my modules locally, tar it, and then send it the tarred Python build to each node using wget or curl, untar it, and then run my program. I believe part of this problem is that the nodes in the cluster use different Linux builds: some use RHEL, some SL, some Debian (see my previous comment.) I will find out, though, about the mounting issue.

Comment: Having nodes with different linux distributions is indeed messy. Well having a shared file system is mostly convenient, you could indeed use a sequence of tar > wget > untar with the same effect. Hopefully you still might be able to build everything on the frontend node and then copy it to all the  other nodes (assuming they are all 64bit), you might need to include a couple more shared libraries, to make sure these are the same (maybe `libc.so`). It should be doable but might be a bit tricky. In the end, maybe, you are right, and building all of the modules on every node would be simpler.

Comment: Do you think doing something like compiling my program to binary using pyinstaller(https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller) and running it as a shell script would work?  Would that in theory be robust to the nodes having different linux distributions?

Comment: @shadowprice Actually yes, that could be worth trying, if simply copying the corresponding .so doesn't work. Although, I'm not sure it handles budling external `.so` unrelated to python (i.e. GSL): you could end doing that manually, which will then remove all advantage of this approach.  For `pyinstaller` use the `--onedir` flag (not the `--onefile`) so you can see what files/libraries it includes.